# List does not contain a definition for 'ConvertAll' and no extension method 'ConvertAll' accepting a first argument of type 'List< >'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a C# project that runs on the Visual Studio's command. It looks like that:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var usuarios = new List<Usuario>() {
                new Usuario() { Id = 5, Grupo = "Diretoria", Nome = "Carlos" },
                new Usuario() { Id = 21, Grupo = "Diretoria", Nome = "José" },
                new Usuario() { Id = 3, Grupo = "RH", Nome = "Camila" },
                new Usuario() { Id = 42, Grupo = "RH", Nome = "Joana" },
                new Usuario() { Id = 102, Grupo = "", Nome = "Joaquim" },
                new Usuario() { Id = 7, Grupo = "RH", Nome = "Camila" },
                new Usuario() { Id = 105, Grupo = "Operações", Nome = "Vitor" }
            };

        /* some non-important codes */

            List<Pessoa> pesssoa = usuarios.ConvertAll(x => new Pessoa
            {
                Nome = x.Nome
            });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Usuario
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Grupo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pessoa
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but I get the error:

> Error CS1061  '`List<Usuario>`' does not contain a definition for
>   'ConvertAll' and no extension method 'ConvertAll' accepting a first
>   argument of type '`List<Usuario>`' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

at the "**ConvertAll**" part. What can possibly be wrong as I'm including the 'using System.Linq' to the project?

Comment: Tested given code and it does not give the error

Comment: @GiladGreen but if here the error is happening then something must be happening

Comment: [works fine on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iLj74O)

Comment: By the way, it has nothing to do with linq : it's a method of `List<T>`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I just said that because all questions that I found about that, the answer whas put the using System.Linq

Comment: @IngridSL - it does not happen in the code you posted. Must be somewhere else or the good old restart VS

Comment: @GiladGreen I already restarted VS and commented everything else

Comment: It looks like you are working in .NET Core project and there is not such method in .NET Core yet.

Comment: @RahulHendawe Current .NET Core does have it. Perhaps older .NET Core didn't?

Comment: The workaround is pretty trivial though: `List<Pessoa> pesssoa = usuarios.Select(x => new Pessoa { Nome = x.Nome }).ToList()`

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy thanks! although I really wanted to use the convertall (as I'm demanded to use it somewhere in the code. I guess I'll try to use somewhere else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out what the problem was. When I created the project on Visual Studio, I selected

File -> New -> Project -> Installed -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Console App (.NET Core)

the problem was selecting *Console App (.NET Core)*. It seems that it doesn't have as many functionalities as the *Console App (.NET Framework)*. Upon creating a new project with Console App (.NET Framework), the ConvertAll worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own extension method for `ConvertAll`:

```
public static class ListExts {
    public static List<Tnew> ConvertAll<Told, Tnew>(this List<Told> src, Func<Told, Tnew> fconv) {
        var ans = new List<Tnew>(src.Count);
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < src.Count; ++j1)
            ans.Add(fconv(src[j1]));
        return ans;
    }
}
```